# ldapadd entries dynamicaly with operational attributes

Tags: openldap

In a multi-master openldap 2.4.X architecture, i want to dynamically add entries with operational attributes, like entryUUID, creatorsName, createTimestamp, modifiersName, entryCSN, modifyTimestamp,pwdChangedTime.

These entries come from exports done with ldapsearch and '+'operationalAttr args ,  from this ldap (before deleting them)  or from other ldap.

Why? For 3 reasons:

1. Because in a multi-master openldap, if you add an already existing entry (dn) by mistake without it's associated entryUUID, openldap considers it is a new one, and in a multi master openldap where each node can destroy entries, if  it thinks he has to , it is not a good choice. This makes a split-brain case.
   Using original entryUUID  prevent this since you cannot add an already existing entryUUID.
2. Because i want to keep history: creatorsName, createTimestamp, modifiersName, entryCSN, modifyTimestamp,pwdChangedTime
3. Because i don't want to use slapcat/slapadd because it needs to stop a node. I want all actions be dynamically done, in a cn=config dynamic way.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does the original source still exist as a server? Syncrepl is how I'd pull this in live.
I suppose you could always stand up a small server after add the relevant entries to it with slapadd.

Comment: @84104 no, there is only an ldif file. adding a new server tool for that, in sync with other server may be a solution.